# How to hide some section in WordPress under Post

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-admin

I have a mobile and I just wondering How to hide some of the sections but keep the functionality under WordPress Post to make it look simpler than what I've right now?

If possible I just want to display only like Categories, Featured Image, and Checklist because these are the only things that I need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On this page in the top right, click the three dots stacked up on each other.  At the bottom of the drop down menu, choose "preferences".

In the preferences window on the left column look for "Panels".  Click it and de-select any times you don't want to show.

After you're done choosing, click the "x" in the top right and you're all set.